# Photoshop: How to know which layer does graphic object inside

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I have met this situation, and because I just learn photoshop so I don't know how to solve this.

I have a psd file contains some layers. Those layers have grouped together. Then I draw a graphic (in my case is an eclipse). AFAIK, when I draw a new graphic object, photoshop will put automatically new object in new layer. I have checked but doesn't see any new layers. I also test by disable each group (click on the eye on the left of the layer) but I always see that graphic object on screen. (So it means this object doesn't contain in any layers, right ? )

The only solution currently is closing document without saving and redo work again.

My question is: where does this graphic object store. And how can I know which layer of some object when I don't know where it come from.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop puts new drawing onto a new layer only when:

- you are creating a vector **shape** (not "path")
  [image]
- **and** existing layers are neither empty nor locked

If you still see your ellipse when all the layers are disabled - then you've drawn a **path**. Undo this and pick "Shape" **tool mode** from a dropdown near the ellipse icon when Ellipse tool is selected (as shown above).

Comment: thanks. I understand right now. can you tell me if I use path, how can I select again this object ? Thanks :)

Comment: And why does photoshop do this ? That shape will be created on new layer, but Path. Are there any reasons ? Thanks :)

Comment: You can select this piece of work with button A on a keyboard, which has two sub-tools:
1) Path Selection Tool (selects the whole path); 2) Direct Selection Tool (allows to work with anchor points).

Comment: As for the second question - can't say for sure. I'm not very well versed in what Paths are exactly used to (and why are they separated from Shapes).

Comment: So. Mostly you use shape rather than path ? I just see some tutorials using path and don't understand so much difference too. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I always work with the Shape option of vector tools (both Pen and preset shapes called by U button) in PhotoShop. May be I'm missing smth :) I'd really like to learn

Comment: I understand :D Thank for your help. I have searched some topics, and I see that no articles tell me shape will create new layer and path will not. This really helps me :D

Comment: Paths are like Channels -- they can be stored, retrieved and repurposed (to become selections, etc.). They are part of the document file, but don't become part of the *image* until you use them for something.

Answer (score 1):

use shortcuts
ctrl + click the object to find the group in window and same for mac opn + click
These shortcuts to find the object on which layer or group.

For path just click on the path tab which is their on right panel where you see layers. you'll get your path of the shape.